# Combined column data need to get as SQL query output

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a functionality to export some records to our database. While exporting any error occur that we are logging into our database.

This is the log table data:

[image]

Now I need to show these records in the following manner:

[image]

This is the SQL query you can use to test

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
(
    ExportId INT,
    AssigneeID INT,
    HomeAssignmentID INT,
    HostAssignmentID INT,
    Error NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP                                                    
SELECT * FROM (                                                  
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3234 AS AssigneeID,0 AS HomeAssignmentID,0 AS HostAssignmentID ,'Gender does not exist' AS Error                          
 UNION ALL                                                             
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3234 AS AssigneeID,2043 AS HomeAssignmentID ,0 AS HostAssignmentID,'Error while processing Assignee' AS Error                       
 UNION ALL      
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3234 AS AssigneeID,2043 AS HomeAssignmentID ,1768 AS HostAssignmentID,'Error while processing Home Assignment' AS Error
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3234 AS AssigneeID,2044 AS HomeAssignmentID ,0 AS HostAssignmentID,'Error while processing Assignee' AS Error
UNION ALL
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3234 AS AssigneeID,2044 AS HomeAssignmentID ,1769 AS HostAssignmentID,'Error while processing Home Assignment' AS Error
UNION ALL
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3577 AS AssigneeID,2058 AS HomeAssignmentID ,0 AS HostAssignmentID,'Home Country does not exist in master data.' AS Error
UNION ALL
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3577 AS AssigneeID,2058 AS HomeAssignmentID ,2011 AS HostAssignmentID,'Host Country does not exist in master data.' AS Error
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3577 AS AssigneeID,2059 AS HomeAssignmentID ,0 AS HostAssignmentID,'Home Country does not exist in master data.' AS Error
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3577 AS AssigneeID,2059 AS HomeAssignmentID ,2012 AS HostAssignmentID,'Error occurred in Assignment Home processing.' AS Error
UNION ALL   
SELECT 1123 AS ExportId,3578 AS AssigneeID,2060 AS HomeAssignmentID ,2015 AS HostAssignmentID,'Host Country does not exist in master data.' AS Error
) AS X
```

Comment: So you need group by the text in a single row?

Comment: yes.. you are correct

Comment: Your picture doesnt match your sample, there are 10 rows in your sample data and 9 in your result picture. So a row is missing?

Comment: Sorry, I updated with new image.

Comment: 2044 has only 2 rows in the data but 3 in the picture :( ??

Comment: Do you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows?  Without that, this may be impossible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think first one is the 0 on `HomeAssignmentID`, then the 0 in `HostAssignmentID` and last the one with a number in `HostAssignmentID`

Comment: @Juan :That record is failed due to Assignee - "3234" is not inserted in the DB. So that one also need to display along with this record too

Comment: So you also need build rows from thin air? I think you should reconsider refactor your table. Can be done but is too messy

Comment: @Gordon :this one should be the order ExportId,AssigneeID,HomeAssignmentID,HostAssignmentID

Comment: @Juan : This is not the real table.Each assignee,HomeAssignment and Host assignment we are getting from different tables.Each types of records (assignee,HomeAssignment and Host assignment )getting from different query and combined  queries with union - that output only i demonstrate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data, you can get the grouping column using window functions and an ordering column:

```
select t.*, t2.error
from (select distinct exportid, assigneeid, HomeAssignmentID, HostAssignmentID
      from t
      where HomeAssignmentID <> 0 and HostAssignmentID <> 0
     ) join
     t t2
     on t2.exportid = t.exportid and t2.assigneeid = t.assigneeid and
        (t2.HomeAssignmentID = t.HomeAssignmentID or t2.HomeAssignmentID = 0)
```

This essentially adds the four columns to each error.  Because of the nature of the data, a given error might be attached to multiple rows.

A group is defined by the four columns in the first subquery.

In SQL Server 2017+, you can then put this in an aggregation query:

```
select exportid, assigneeid, HomeAssignmentID, HostAssignmentID,
       string_agg(error, '
') within group (order by hostassignmentid, homeassignmentid) as error
from (select t.*, t2.error
      from (select distinct exportid, assigneeid, HomeAssignmentID, HostAssignmentID
            from #temp 5
            where HomeAssignmentID <> 0 and HostAssignmentID <> 0
           ) join
           #temp t2
           on t2.exportid = t.exportid and t2.assigneeid = t.assigneeid and
              (t2.HomeAssignmentID = t.HomeAssignmentID or t2.HomeAssignmentID = 0)

           ) t
      ) t
group by exportid, assigneeid, HomeAssignmentID, HostAssignmentID;
```

In earlier versions, you need XML:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, t2.error
      from (select distinct exportid, assigneeid, HomeAssignmentID, HostAssignmentID
            from t
            where HomeAssignmentID <> 0 and HostAssignmentID <> 0
           ) join
           t t2
           on t2.exportid = t.exportid and t2.assigneeid = t.assigneeid and
              (t2.HomeAssignmentID = t.HomeAssignmentID or t2.HomeAssignmentID = 0)
     )
select exportid, assigneeid, HomeAssignmentID,
       stuff( (select '
' + error
               from t t2
               where t2.exportid = t.exportid and t2.assigneeid = t.assigneeid and
                     t2.HomeAssignmentID = t.HomeAssignmentID and
                     t2.HostAssignmentID = t.HostAssignmentID
               order by t2.hostassignmentid, t2.homeassignmentid
               for xml path ('') type
              ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
                     ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as error
from (select distinct exportid, assigneeid, HomeAssignmentID, HostAssignmentID
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: That doesnt match OP desire output. Create only 3 groups. http://rextester.com/TKOIO30687

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Much more complicated than I first thought -- and I already thought it was pretty complicated.

Comment: @SajithA.K. Even when this produce the correct result, Doesn't guarantee the order for the errors ( at least I think doesn't). So be careful if that is important for you.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . I had the `order by` in the `string_agg()` version.  I added it to the last query.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : thanks a lot.I have taken 3rd query. my sql is 2012.Getting the result as expected :). For ordering the error message -       
select ROW_Number() over ( order by..) rowid,  exportid, assigneeid, HomeAssignmentID, HostAssignmentID from t. That is worked for me.                                                              .And I replaced "Distinct" with "Order by" also.